# How to dispose of a UIButton's Image Contents only, not the button itself

Tags: ios, xamarin, uibutton, uiimage, dispose

Say I have a UIButton and I gave it a background image, like so:

```
UIButton button = new (....);
button.SetBackroundImage = UIImage.FromFile(....);
```

How do I dispose of the buttons image without holding onto the image variable?  I tried the below code but it doesn't appear to work.

```
button.CurrentBackgroundImage.Dispose()
```

My case here, is that I have a collectionview with 10 visible items but could have hundreds of things in it.  Obviously it's only reusing 10 cells with 10 uibuttons.  The images getting drawn and set as the background image of the UIButtons are drawn dynamically and need to be disposed of once you scroll away and reload the re-usable collection view cell

Answer (score 0):

Just set the image to nil. iOS will dispose of the image when necessary.

```
[button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For Xamarin specific Dispose usage check [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/).

Comment: I update the above post adding more information.  I am using a dynamically created image which needs Disposed of, not nulled.  Will setting a new image like that dispose of the old one?

Comment: You don't need to dispose the image as that will happen when setting the image to nil.

Comment: If this is something Xamarin specific you could try grabbing a reference to the image first, set the UIButton.image to nil, then run dispose on the referenced image. Generally in iOS the caching controller handles all this "voodoo".

Answer (score 0):

Using `IDisposable` pattern in C#:

```
using (var image = UIImage.FromFile ("yourImageFile.png")){
    button.SetBackroundImage = image;
}
```